# map array to ajax request and wait for all to complete

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to run an ajax request on each element of an array. Basically a post request to a php server.

But what is the appropriate way to wait for this result to be completed? What is wrong with the code I wrote below? I need the `console.log("step2")` to print only after all of the ajax requests are completed.

```
var results = await Promise.all(
    some_array.map(function(val, key){
        return(
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<some/link/to/php/server>',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: val.id,
                xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
                async: true
            }).done(function(response){         
                run_this_code
            })
        )
    })
)
console.log("step2");
```

Thanks!

Comment: put the console.log inside `.then(console.log(...))` following the Promise.all() (instead of await)

Comment: this "should" work with the `console.log` where it is, due to the `await`. I think the problem is that `jQuery.ajax` does not return a Promise, so `await` doesn't await it properly.

Comment: Your code should already do what you're requesting, assuming it's in an async function and not throwing an error for not being in an async function. (and assuming no xhr errors are occurring)

Comment: If I copy and paste the code, as is, into a browser, step2 prints before the map function is complete. @KevinB

Comment: @Andy I want step 2 to occur after all the array elements are mapped as the next step needs the entire mapped array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how jQuery's `ajax` works, but you can try this:

```
var results = await Promise.all(
    some_array.map(function(val, key){
            return jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<some/link/to/php/server>',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: val.id,
                xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
                async: true
            })
    })
)
console.log("step2");
```

Also I would use `fetch` or `axios` since they are more modern.
With `fetch` it would look something like this

```
const results = await Promise.all(
  some_array.map((val, key) => fetch('<some/link/to/php/server>', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify(val.id)
  }).then(res => res.json()))
)
```

I used modern JavaScript syntax, but you can use the old one as well

Comment: jQuery ajax methods *do* return promises.

Comment: @KevinB yrs this is true. I didn't expect library so old to support it.

Comment: Hi are you saying I can't have the .done processing step in the map function?

Comment: @Frank do you want to run something on every request done? I thought you want to wait for all of them.